# Error when unzipping a file

Tags: zip

I am getting the following error when unzipping a file

```
unzip user_file_batch1.csv.zip

Archive:  user_file_batch1.csv
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.

unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of user_file_batch1.csv or
        user_file_batch1.csv.zip, and cannot find user_file_batch1.csv.ZIP, period.
```

I believe this file is not corrupted or a part of multi archive file as using Archive Utility I was able to unzip it.
I have tried to rename it to `.zip` but did not work.

The output of `type file user_file_batch1.csv.zip` was

```
user_file_batch1.csv.zip: uuencoded or xxencoded text
```

Comment: type `file user_file_batch1.csv.zip` — tell us what the output is.

Comment: The output was user_file_batch1.csv.zip: uuencoded or xxencoded text

Comment: It is not a zip, you need to uudecode it. Then use file to see what you have. (Look at @giles's answer).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your file has a `.zip` name, but is not in zip format. Renaming a file doesn't change its content, and in particular doesn't magically transform it into a different format.

(Alternatively, the same error could happen with an incomplete zip file — but since that Archive Utility worked, this isn't the case.)

Run `file user_file_batch1.csv.zip` to see what type of file this is. It's presumably some other type of archive that Archive Utility understands.

> user_file_batch1.csv.zip: uuencoded or xxencoded text

Run the following command:

```
uudecode user_file_batch1.csv.zip
```

This creates a file whose name is indicated in `user_file_batch1.csv.zip`. If you want to pick a different output file name:

```
uudecode -o user_file_batch1.csv.decoded user_file_batch1.csv.zip
```

The output file at this stage may, itself, be an archive. (Perhaps it's a zip, in fact.) Run the `file` utility again on this file to see what it is. If you choose the automatic file name, it might give a clue.

Comment: On Mac, `file /users/an/zz.zip` says """Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract""". But trying to unzip, it says """Archive:  /users/an/zz.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
Archive:  /users/an/zz.ZIP
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes

Comment: one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive."""

Comment: @Pacerier So? It's either a damaged zip, or a zip that uses some feature that your version of unzip doesn't support, or a part of a multi-part zip, or something that was never meant to be a zip but happens to look like one superficially. It's impossible to tell without knowing what's in the file.

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar problem when doing `unzip archive.zip`, giving  me

> Archive:  archive.zip
>   warning [archive.zip]:  ...  extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
>     (attempting to process anyway)
>   error [archive.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
>   zipfile corrupt.
>   (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
>   appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)

Doing `file archive.zip` gave me

> Zip archive data

Using `7z e archive.zip` worked.

Comment: This isn't the answer to the OP, but it IS the answer to mine :) Thanks, I didn't know that 7zip was available in Linux.

Comment: this works ! I wish thre was a way to tell that this is a 7z archive, rather than a regular zip. `file` does not indicate anything

Comment: `7z x archive.zip` might be a better option

Answer (score 5):

Go to your zip location then unzip by this command

```
jar xvf yourzipfile.zip
```

Comment: My sqlworkbench zip file was corrupted due to improper shutdown. This helped me to recover at least 6 tabs out of 9. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with unzip.

Then I tried to extract it with 7z and jar without any luck. Later it turned out that the it was a quiet old p7zip version.

I installed a new one from [source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/) and that solved the issue. A simple:

```
7z x archive.zip
```

extracted it out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy the text content in the zip file just gzip the file for file format and for listing the content use zcat

```
# unzip ADUReport.zip
Archive:  ADUReport.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of ADUReport.zip or
        ADUReport.zip.zip, and cannot find ADUReport.zip.ZIP, period.
 #gunzip ADUReport.zip
gunzip: ADUReport.zip: unknown suffix -- ignored
 zcat ADUReport.zip

#zcat: ADUReport.zip: not in gzip format
#gzip ADUReport.zip
#l
 #zcat ADUReport.zip.gz
```

Comment: Apart from that this doesn't answer the OPs question, explaining why `gzip`-ping a file and then `zcat`-ting instead of using `cat` on the original file helps  (unless you are paid by the hour).

Answer (score 0):

Got this in someones script when it unpacks a bunch on zips like that

```
unzip -o -q 'prefix*'
```

and there where files with the same prefix inside zips.

Fixed with

```
unzip -o -q 'prefix*.zip'
```